# Calculating a seen height of an object from a scope

Tags: geometry, relations

I have an object that is 0.6 meter in diameter that stand at 1000 meter away from me, I have a scope with magnification of X15-40.

How can I calculate the size of the image that I will see through the scope at the minimum and maximum magnification values?

Answer (score 0):

The angular size of the image will be:
$$
2\arctan\left(X\cdot\frac{0.3}{1000}\right)\approx\frac{0.6X}{1000}.
$$

In other words the object will seem to be $X$ times closer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. X stand for the power of magnification?

Comment: @איתישולמן Yes, it does.